# Better rules for gnu make with docker

Tags: docker, makefile

Suppose my source files are located in

```
~/dev/root
```

Inside `~/dev/root` are a number of projects.

e.g.

```
~/dev/root/libraries/libx
~/dev/root/apps/app/appy
~/dev/root/docker/appy
```

The build tool I use is called tundra2 and is invoked from the root level.

So if I run tundra2 production appy it'll produce it's output to

```
~/dev/root/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default
```

The binary is directly below that directory.  There are also intermediate files located within sub-directories in that directory.

Now the annoying bit.  For whatever reason, docker build uses a daemon process that copies everything from the directory it's being run from to a temporary directory.  It then produces it's image from there.  I haven't yet spent the time to try and extend tundra2 to cope with docker so I've been using a Makefile.

So inside the docker/appy directory I have my Dockerfile.  Alongside I have a makefile.  The idea is to cd into that directory and run make.
If everything builds, it should copy the outputs from t2-output into the docker/appy directory and run docker build.

So far, I've specified the build targets like:

```
T2OUT=../../t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default
TAG = "appy"
all: $(T2OUT)/appy

$(T2OUT)/appy: 
     cd $(T2OUT) && tundra2 production appy
     cp $< .
     docker build -t $(TAG) .
```

etc

The above is very cumbersome.  So I tried experimenting below with VPATH but that doesn't work.  `make --debug=v` confirms it. Can you suggest an alternative?  (I might even consider another build tool provided it isn't npm based)

VPATH=../../t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default
%.so: 
  ...

Sometimes I run the tundra2 build directly from ~/dev/root

So what I'm trying to get make to do is detect that appy and the copied appy are different.

i.e.  if `~/dev/root/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default/appy` is different to: `~/dev/root/cluster/docker/appy/appy`

Then copy `~/dev/root/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default/appy` to `~/dev/root/cluster/docker/appy/appy`

And if `~/dev/root/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default/appy` doesn't exist, even if `~/dev/root/cluster/docker/appy/appy` does exist, we should go to ../../.. run tundra2 and copy the output as above to the docker/appy directory so that we can run docker build

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation I found this works well.  It's quite generic.  So I just need to make sure, BUILDROOT is right for the location of the makefile and SERVICES is correct.  I can probably set BUILDROOT in my environment.

```
BUILDROOT=../../..
T2OUT=$(BUILDROOT)/t2-output/linux64-gcc-production-default
TUNDRA2=cd $(BUILDROOT); tundra2 production
DOCKER_TAG=remoteregistry.example.com/path/appy

SERVICES=appy

all: $(SERVICES)
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_TAG) .

# For some libraries the build target is different so I had to specify the 
# build dependancy
$(T2OUT)/lib.so:
    $(TUNDRA2) target

$(T2OUT)/%: 
    $(TUNDRA2) $*

%: $(T2OUT)/%
    cp $< $@

clean: $(SERVICES)
    rm -f $(SERVICES)

.PHONY: all clean
```